# How can we create custom view over UITableViewController in Swift (StoryBoard)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, albumart

I am using a `UITableViewController` for create an album in my iOS application. Now i want to create a custom view over the `UITableViewController`. The view must have two button for MOVE and DELETE.  how can I achieve this scenario in swift? is it possible to design the custom view in storyboard?

Comment: you can try some libraries..have you tried ?

Comment: @Jok3r I didn't find any library support this feature. can you suggest any library?

Comment: you can use header view of tableview. just drag and drop a view on tableview and keep it at the top of every cell

Comment: @KeshuRai I did this method, but the view is also get scrolled while scrolling tableview. I need a static view

Comment: Then the best way is to create a UIView xib and then place it in header using viewForHeaderInSection method

Comment: You can add a tableview inside the viewcontroller and you can place buttons inside the view conteroller and bottom of that you can set the tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to drag a normal view and put on the top of your UITableView
[image]

It will seen like this

[image]

You can set an IBOutlet to it. Set its frame. Add buttons and add it to your view like any other views

```
self.view.addSubview(THIS_VIEW)
```

Comment: I did this, but the view is also get scrolled while scrolling tableview. I need a static view

Comment: You need to have a normal view Controller and add a UITableView to it.
OR you can use tableView.scrollEnabled = false when THIS_VIEW is on screen then tableView.scrollEnabled = true when THIS_VIEW is not on screen. The first option is recommended

Answer (score 1):

From storyboard add a view controller, once you have added it insert a table view object (Not table view controller) and a view anywhere you want.